# WSO2ESB js script mediator error on big payload

Tags: javascript, json, wso2-esb

I have a seq (WSO2ESb 4.9) calls REST and receives JSON. Then I map JSON to XML via script mediator (JS), here is my configuration:

```
<case regex="urn:mta:navigation:getMarshes">
                <property xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="uri.var.service"
                    value="getMarshes" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                <call>
                    <endpoint key="adapter.navigation.asu.GetData.Endpoint" />
                </call>
                <script language="js"><![CDATA[
                            var array = mc.getPayloadJSON();
                            var payload = <getMarshesRS/>;     

                            for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                                var elem = array[i];
                                payload.Marshes += <marsh id={elem.mr_id} num={elem.mr_num} title={elem.mr_title} note={elem.mr_note} mt_id={elem.mrt_id} />
                            }
                            mc.setPayloadXML(payload);
                ]]></script>
</case>
```

If I receive not much objects from REST service (10 for example), it works fine. But if I receive 1280 objects, I have an exception

> [2016-08-23 16:31:35,799] ERROR -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 186472 in class file org/mozilla/javascript/gen/c187
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.DefiningClassLoader.defineClass(DefiningClassLoader.java:62)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.defineClass(Codegen.java:126)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.createScriptObject(Codegen.java:81)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2361)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Context.java:1310)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Context.java:1282)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1224)
>       at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:172)
>       at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.processJSONPayload(ScriptMediator.java:322)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:294)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:239)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:207)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:178)
>       at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:679)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:244)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in ESB where you cannot process large payloads with script mediator, this is coming from the underline Rhino Engine. Following is the JIRA for this. But your stack-trace is somewhat different.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4834